# Creating a picture slider for a website

Tags: javascript, html, web, slider

I am trying to create a **picture slider** on a website I'm building.

When searching for examples online, I've found very complex examples with great amounts of JavaScript code or suggestions to use Dreamweaver-type software.

Isn't there a simple, HTML5 integrated/built-in way to create a picture slider?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the slick plugin, it's very useful for carousels.

Documentation here:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

add this into your `<head>` tag to initialize the plugin default style:

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.css"/>

// Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick-theme.css"/>
```

then before your `</body>` tag do:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Example:

HTML

```
<div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
// On swipe event
$('.your-element').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log(direction);
  // left
});

// On edge hit
$('.your-element').on('edge', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log('edge was hit')
});

// On before slide change
$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

This example was taken from: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick